# Which formula to use for logistic regression with different predictors?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, binary-data

I'm doing a logistic regression with "Choice" (Yes or No) as dependent variable and 3 different predictors, including reward, demand (5 level each) and condition (0 or 1) and their interaction, as well as the participants ID as a random effect (it's a between-group design, so a single ID per participant). Based on literature, I found two different formulas that were used in similar analysis. Now the thing is that both formulas give different results.

Formula 1 tells me that there are 2 significant interaction effects, whereas formula 2 tells me that there is only 1 significant interaction effect. Since my interpretation depends largely on the interaction effects, I am uncertain which formula to use and which result to report.

These are the formulas I've been using

1. 'Choice ~ 1 + Reward x Demand xCondition + (1|ID)'
   and
2. 'Choice ~ Reward x Demand x Condition + (1 + Reward + Demand + Condition|ID)'

I used both codes in R and Matlab, it's alway the same results.

I'd appreciate every help of you people!

Comment: Hint: first choice is a random-intercept model, whereas the second one has both random intercepts and random slopes. Do you want the slopes to vary across groups?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not 100 percent sure if I really got it, but random slope basically implies that the predictor may have different effects for each group, right? Since "condition" actually refers to two different samples with different clinical features, I guess I should prefer the model with random intercept and random slope, i.e. formula 2, right?